# How to use YELP API with OAuthSwift?

Tags: swift, api, oauth-2.0, token, yelp

I'm trying to use OAuthSwift with the Yelp API. One of the required parameters is requestTokenURL, authorizeURL, accessTokenURL; however, I already have the token itself from Yelp and there is no authorize URL for Yelp. Not including these parameters gives me an error. What is the correct way to use OAuthSwift with the Yelp API? Thank you.

```
 func OAuthVerify(){
    let oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
        consumerKey: "#",
        consumerSecret: "#",
        requestTokenUrl: "???",
        authorizeUrl:    "???",
        accessTokenUrl:  "???"
    )
    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/")!, success: { (credential, response, parameters) -> Void in
        self.grabYelpData(oauthswift,consumerKey: "RZKQlWV3nqdB-74fZZRQeg")
        }) { (error) -> Void in
            print("error")
    }
}

func grabYelpData(oauthswift: OAuth1Swift, consumerKey: String){
    let url :String = "https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?"
    let parameters :Dictionary = [
        "term"           : "food",
        //"api_key"        : consumerKey,
        "location"       : "San Francisco",
    ]
    oauthswift.client.get(url, parameters: parameters,
        success: {
            data, response in
            let jsonDict: AnyObject! = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
            print(jsonDict)
        }, failure: { error in
            print(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: This lib may help using Yelp with Swift: https://github.com/dalequi/yelpitoff

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for the same thing, and this is the only thing I've found so far and it seems to work and return the proper data from Yelp.

```
let oauthswift  = OAuth1Swift(
        consumerKey: "*********",
        consumerSecret: "*************",
        requestTokenUrl: "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token",
        authorizeUrl:    "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl:  "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token"
    )

    oauthswift.client.credential.oauth_token =  "*******"
    oauthswift.client.credential.oauth_token_secret = "*******"

    oauthswift.client.get("https://api.yelp.com/v2/search/...",
        success: {
            data, response in
            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            self.printYelpData(data)
            print(dataString)
        }
        , failure: { error in
            print(error)
        }
    )
```

I tried to just leave the requestTokenUrl, etc. blank, but it didn't work, so I just put in a URL that was supported, and then set it after the initialization.

I hope that helps!